# How to make this select function work in R?

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I'm trying to create a function to extract certain columns from a data set. I tried this:

```
extract <- function(x) {
 x <- select(filter(df),c(id,x))
}  

extract(df$var1)
```

in which `id` is an identification variable. But there's an error message saying:

> Error: c(id, x) must evaluate to column positions or names, not a double vector

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are trying to do is

```
library(dplyr)

extract <- function(df, x, id_t){
   select(filter(df, id == id_t), x)
}
```

You can now call this function as

```
extract(df, 2:5, 20)
```

This will select columns 2-5 where `id` value is 20 in `df`.

---

Using an example from `mtcars`

```
extract <- function(df, x, id){
   select(filter(df, cyl == id), x)
}
extract(mtcars, 2:5, 6)

#  cyl  disp  hp drat
#1   6 160.0 110 3.90
#2   6 160.0 110 3.90
#3   6 258.0 110 3.08
#4   6 225.0 105 2.76
#5   6 167.6 123 3.92
#6   6 167.6 123 3.92
#7   6 145.0 175 3.62
```

Here it selects columns 2-5 from `mtcars` dataset where `cyl = 6`.